# Figure-8 Followthrough Question

Tags: rock-climbing, knots

Is it still considered a 'figure 8' knot when you dress it so the loop is perpendicular to the rest of the loop?

[image: sideways figure eight knot]
[image: normal figure eight knot]

Comment: Can you post a picture from a different angle? Maybe I am just clumsy, but I failed to dress it in the manner shown.

Comment: Related https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18814/how-to-tie-a-figure-eight-on-a-bight?noredirect=1&lq=1 
 and https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5007/how-do-i-tie-a-figure-of-8-knot

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, **regardless of how as you dress it, that is still a figure 8 knot.**

It's not going to matter either, because once the knot is weighted, it will be pulled into the same configuration regardless of the angle the loop is dressed to.

In other words, the top picture will look like the bottom once force is applied.

Comment: Would love to see a link with data from a stress test that shows the dressing does not make a difference.

Comment: Agreed on the stress test.  Every time the rope is "bent" through a knot, it weakens the rope (not the knot).  The more severe the bend, the more the rope is weakened because the fibers are no longer aligned optimally.  I suspect in this case it would be minimal (as indicated, the knot would correct itself), but I wouldn't take the risk myself.  Is there a reason?